# Reading csv file in pySpark with double quotes and newline character

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having problems with reading csv files using pySpark. I have three columns with url address, title (string) and full html file. The last field is in quotes "..." and anything quoted inside of it has double quotes e.g "test" -> ""test"" (it also contains newline character as well). I can read this file using pandas and everything is fine, but when I am using pySpark it does not break the text on coma (,) delimiter (I am not sure but maybe on newline character that is inside html). Here is a sample code:

```
df = spark.read \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .csv('path_to_file')

print( df.limit(2).collect() )
```

Here is a sample text that does not work:

```
url,body,title
https://test.com,"<!doctype html >
</html>",title_title
```

BTW vim shows `^M` at the end of `html >`. Maybe this is causing problems?

UPDATE
After some tries I came into conclusion that pyspark interprets newline character inside quotes as start of another line. But it only does that if I press "Enter" in the file as a jump to new line. If write explicitly `\n`, then it works. 
This piece works:

```
url,body,title
https://test.com,"<!doctype html >\n</html>",title_title
```

Pandas works with both versions!

Comment: try this option `option("quote", "\"")`

Comment: @chlebek I tried both "quote" and "escape" and it does not work

Answer (score 17):

This seems to work:

```
df = (spark.read
      .option("multiline", "true")
      .option("quote", '"')
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("escape", "\\")
      .option("escape", '"')
      .csv('path_to_file')
)
```

Tested with `scala_2.11.0` and `spark_2.3.4_hadoop2.7`

Comment: Above mentioned options can be used too, for writing spark data frames into CSV files

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, including option in your Spark Reading Config works out.

```
 sc.read\
        .option("multiline", "true")\
        .option("quote", '"')\
        .option("header", "true")\
        .option("escape", "\\")\
        .option("escape", '"')\
        .csv(f'{getpathfile()}/files/{file}.csv')
```